# how do I change my windows system from Hebrew to English?

Tags: windows-10

I have Window-10. and I would like to change the language in my PC from Hebrew to English. I tried the following: Setting -> Time and Language -> and the English language is listed in the Prefer Languages List. What should I need do now? How can I change the English language to the default language? Please let me know what's the next step that I need to do.

Thanks in advance!
[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXCwX.png)

Comment: What have you tried?  What edition of Windows 10 do you have exactly?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment in response to these questions.

Comment: You have improved the quality of the question by a fraction but it’s not clear what edition of Windows 10 you are running.  Please edit your question and provide a screenshot of the installed languages that are shown within Settings

Comment: @Ramhound - thanks!
but how can I know what edition of Windows 10 do I have?

Comment: You will have to provided a basic translation within your screenshot.  I can't provide any additional instructions based of that single screenshot that isn't in English.

Answer (score 1):

To change the language for the windows operating system:

1. Go to Settings -> Time and Language -> Language
2. Select the desired language from the 'Windows display language (שפה)' dropdown
3. Sign out of windows and sign back in

Comment: thanks! but I can not change the language. It's impossible.

Comment: What happens? Getting any error message?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? Keyboard, app languages? Answer above is for the operating system.

Comment: yes, I want to change the operation system.

Answer (score 0):

I think what worked for me was to first add English as a preferred language (שפה מועדפת or something like that) and then to press the arrow buttons to make English on top and then  to remove (הסר) the Hebrew option, and then I clicked on the "options" for the English and then there was a new option to update English (עדכון or something like that), and then after all this there was an option available by the system drop-down to change it to English. Although, I haven't figured out how to change everything to English. Like My Documents and things like that are still in Hebrew.